# Find the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty } \,\cos (1) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots \cos \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \,\cos (1) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots \cos \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$$

How would you evaluate this limit? Is it just equivalent to $$\prod_{n=0}^\infty {\cos \left( \frac{1}{2^{n}} \right)}$$

Comment: The latter is defined as the earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Multiply first by $2^{n+1}\sin(1/2^n)$ and collapse it.

Comment: I don't quite follow. How does multiplying by that allow you to simplify it?

Comment: Use $2\cos(x)\sin(x)=\sin(2x)$. The $\sin$, the $\cos$ and the $2$ collapse in another $\sin$ (which you can use for the next cosinus).

Comment: But doesn't multiplying by that change the value of the limit?

Comment: Yes, you multiply and divide by it. The multiply one you use to collapse it. The divide part remains to compute the limit.

Comment: When you collapse it do you end up with 2*sin(1)?

Comment: I think the $\cos(1)$ collapses too with the $\sin(1)$. So we get $\sin(2)$. But divided by what we multiplyed by (divided by $2^{n+1}\sin(1/2^{n+1})$).

Comment: Got it -- the answer is just sin(2), right? At the beginning I got why you multiplied by sin(1/2^n), but why did you use 2^n+1 instead of just 2^n?

Comment: Because $1=2^{0}, 2=2^1, ..., 2^{n}=2^n$. So, then numbers $0,1,...,n$ are $n+1$ numbers.

Comment: Don't worry about the chat thing. Your questions might be the next guy's questions, so it is not bad if they can see the answers here.

Comment: So is sin(2) the right answer? Because when I evaluated with mathematica it gives sin(1)*cos(1)

Comment: Check the cancelling of the $2$'s. Notice that $\sin(1)\cos(1)=2\sin(1)\cos(1)/2=\sin(2)/2$.

Comment: I keep getting sin(2) when I collapse the products... I should be getting sin(2)/2, right? Perhaps you could explain the method to collapse it?

Comment: I think you might be computing wrong the limit. Notice that $\lim 2^{n+1}\sin(1/2^n)=2\lim \frac{\sin(1/2^n)}{1/2^n}=2$.

Comment: Ah, you were right -- I forgot about the n+1 in the limit. Thanks!